# How to add padding only in lg devices in Ion 5 grid

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am trying to add padding to `ion-grid` only in lg devices. The documentation of [ion-grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid)
suggests `--ion-grid-padding-lg`, but it doesn't work in below scenario.

```
<ion-grid class="grid-pay-now">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="12" size-sm class="ion-text-justify">
          <div>
            <ion-text color="secondary">
              <h2>Pay online</h2>
            </ion-text>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ion-text class="title">
                            Quick Payment
                        </ion-text>
                        <h2 class="ion-padding-top">
                            <p>Our client may have asked us to get in touch with you. Don't worry, we're friendly and
                                great listeners.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                We'll show you how you can pay, talk to us about your repayments, or help you if you're
                                having some difficulties.
                            </p>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

scss file

```
.grid-pay-now
{
  --ion-grid-padding-lg: 50px; // this doesn't work
  // --ion-grid-padding: 50px; // this works for all devices, but I don't want for all devices
}
```

How can I add padding to the grid only to lg devices?

Comment: Its surprising that one value works while the second one doesn't. The width of the screen needs to be 992px before lg attributes take effect. Are you sure this condition is being met ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in iPadPro or width > 1000px, it's working fine